# How to get parent ViewGroup of libgdx game?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, android-view

I'm trying to add banners ads to my game and for that I need the parent ViewGroup of my libgdx game. My code is:

```
final Activity activity = (Activity) this;
final ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0); // exception here
```

However the game crashes when I try this with the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException:
  com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.surfaceview.GLSurfaceView20
    cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
```

Comment: You are most likely mixing two different classes that have the same name `ViewGroup`. From the exception you can see that it expects `android.view.ViewGroup`, try providing the full classname and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, `initializeForView` method return `View` so get and add to your own layout and at the end setContentView to layout by `setContentView` method.

```
public RelativeLayout layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        layout.setLayoutParams(params);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        View gameView=initializeForView(new Main(), config);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams gameViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        gameViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        gameViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        gameView.setLayoutParams(gameViewParams);

        layout.addView(gameView);
        //create banner view and embed/add into layout 

        setContentView(layout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your root layout is `GLSurfaceView20` which is a descendant of `SurfaceView`, which is a descendant of `View`, **not** a `ViewGroup`.

> How to get parent ViewGroup of libgdx game?

Answering your question: the parent may or may not be a `ViewGroup` (in your case it is not). You can get the content `View` and perform `instanceof` test to see whether it is a descendant of a `ViewGroup`